# is background list of genes in CluoGO in Cytoscape are modify for gene enrichment analysis?

Tags: ontology, cytoscape

I want to modify background list gene in the CluoGO. anybody know hot i can change the list of this genes for gene enrichment analysis? and use the restricted list for background.
thanks

There are not any options for the modify of gene list background in the cluoGO now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are still looking for it, would this be helpful?
Statistical options > Reference set options > Custom Reference Set

[Image: clueGO custom reference set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orvd9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would reach out to the ClueGO authors for detailed questions about ClueGO (they are usually very responsive), but I think you'll find that they've already talked about this on the [cytoscape-helpdesk](https://groups.google.com/g/cytoscape-helpdesk/c/Bxt9jfJetdk/m/o4Y9dkTECAAJ).

Comment: Thanks Scooter for your response, ive seen this comment but its about 2018 and doing that manually, maybe they have added some options to modify the background list during these years! idk!